# Moqui: How to add an extra Header in JSON Request?

Tags: json, api, rest, moqui

I am trying to build a Moqui service to pull and push data from a remote REST JSON api but they require that I authenticate using a custom header e.g. 
`X-App-Access-Token: {access_token}` and I can't seem to find a way to add this header when calling the API from a service?

`<service verb="get" noun="Orders" type="remote-json-rpc" location="https://example.com/admin/orders.json">
        <in-parameters>
            <parameter name="marketplaceId"/>
            <parameter name="accessToken"/>
        </in-parameters>
        <actions>
            <service-call name="create#mantle.order.OrderHeader" in-map="context" out-map="context"/>
        </actions>
    </service>`

Thanks for any help!

Sam

Comment: How this is done is heavily dependent on how you are currently accessing the service and with which programming. Share some code, show us what you tried.

Comment: Just updated with a service example that I started to write. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First some notes: The way you have your service setup it wall call the remote JSON RPC service and generally it is best to have a separate service call this service and another local service to create the order. For more complex data structures like an order it is usually best to call one of the services (like OrderServices.create#Order which creates the OrderHeader and one OrderPart) instead of a simple crud implicitly defined auto entity service.

A local service setup like this to be a placeholder for a remote JSON-RPC service is handled by the RemoteJsonRpcServiceRunner.runJsonService() method. That method is static and you can call it directly too. It calls the StupidWebUtilities.simpleHttpStringRequest() method which is where the HttpClient stuff is, and where you would need to add a custom header.

In the current code there is no way to do this. The two methods mentioned above could be extended to support something like an additional headers Map, which might not be a bad idea as it may be useful in other scenarios. You could also just write your own method or service script snippet that does what those do, it is fairly simple code.